# Angular skip-to-main content link SPA problems

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, accessibility, single-page-application

I've been trying and searching a lot but got stuck, so much appreciate any help here.

My task: to implement accessibility feature on Angular 8 app - Skip to main content link to provide users possibility to tab over focusable elements and the first one must be Skip-to-main content link. If they clicked it they will skip all menu navs and go to main content directly.

So, I've implemented that link to header component and made it number 1 focusable element to every component:

```
<header-component>
      <div ><span tabindex="-1"></span>
        <a [href]="skipPath" class="skip">skip to main content</a>
      </div>
<nav>navs</nav>
</header-component>

<about-component>
<div id= "main-content">Main</div>
</about-component>
```

And then to provide appropriate path into skipPath variable added next:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe((event: any) => {
              this.skipPath = `${event.url}#main-content`;          
              document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].focus();
           });
}
```

result:
http://localhost:4200/about#main-content

I've got it work, it listens which page now I'm in, generate right URL, but then it doesn't go there. Actually it jumps where it has to be but immediately return where it was (top of the page).

Any thoughts?

Comment: It appears that you are setting focus on the first span element. Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: yes, because I want it to be the first focused element on the page by default. When user hit tab button for the first time focuse moves and "activate" my skip-to-main content link (that is hidden and appears only if tab button is clicked). Problem is that then this link doesn't path me to #main-content..